# Java - How to extract a substring from start until the end of a particular word in a string?

Tags: java, string, substring

**Input string:**

```
String sentence = "I am an Administrator of my building";
```

**Desired Output String** = `"I am an Administrator"`

Pattern for extracting the substring: Get the substring starting from the beginning of the '`sentence`' string and until the end of the word '`Administrator`'.

I could get the `endIndex` of 'Administrator' and then use `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it.
What would the efficient or short way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to the rescue:

```
String start = sentence.replaceAll("(?<=Administrator).*", "");
```

This works by matching everything after `Administrator` and replacing it with nothing (effectively "deleting" it).

The key part of the regex is the look behind `(?<=Administrator)`, which matches immediately after `Administrator` - *between* the `r` and the space.

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` is what you need. Try:

```
sentence.substring(0, sentence.indexOf(“Administrator”) + ”Administrator”.length())
```

Comment: (Except with `"` instead of smart quotes)

Answer (score 1):

use substring method
ex
String s = "hello"

```
s.substring(0,2)
```

output = he
in your example it will be

```
sentence.substring(0,21)
```

Comment: This isn't really helpful because you don't explain how to choose the `21` - if you're going to have a hard-coded value, you may as well just hard-code `"I am an Administrator"`, because at least you can easily see what that means. You should explain how to choose the 21 at runtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would write a method to take a sentence and its replacement.  The following also preserves end of sentence punctuation.

```
String[][] sentences = {
        {"I am an Administrator of my building.", "Administrator"},
        {"I am a teacher of math students.", "teacher"},
        {"I am a parent of two children!!", "parent"}};

for(String[] info : sentences) {
    String result = trimAfterWord(info[0], info[1]);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

prints

```
I am an Administrator.
I am a teacher.
I am a parent!!
```

- `(?i)` - do case independent matching for word.  Existing case of word will be kept in result.
- `(.*?)` - do a reluctant match to ensure grabbing all punctuation if it exists.
- `$` - only preserve punctuation at end of sentence.
- `$1$2` - back references to captured `word` and `Punct`

```
public static String trimAfterWord(String sentence, String word) {
    return sentence.replaceFirst("(?i)("+word+").*?(\\p{Punct}*)$", "$1$2");
}
```

For more useful information on regular expressions and pattern matching check out [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#indexOf(str:String):int` in various ways to grab parts of string efficiently.

```java
public class StringUtils {
    public static final String sentence = "I am an Administrator of my building";
    public static final String term = "Administrator";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // "I am an Administrator"
        System.out.println(headStringInclusive(sentence, term));

        // "Administrator of my building"
        System.out.println(tailStringInclusive(sentence, term));

        // "I am an "
        System.out.println(headStringExclusive(sentence, term));

        // " of my building"
        System.out.println(tailStringExclusive(sentence, term));
    }

    public static String headStringInclusive(String str, String term) {
        int index = str.indexOf(term);
        return index != -1 ? str.substring(0, index + term.length()) : str;
    }

    public static String tailStringInclusive(String str, String term) {
        int index = str.lastIndexOf(term);
        return index != -1 ? str.substring(index) : str;
    }

    public static String headStringExclusive(String str, String term) {
        int index = str.indexOf(term);
        return index != -1 ? str.substring(0, index) : str;
    }

    public static String tailStringExclusive(String str, String term) {
        int index = str.lastIndexOf(term);
        return index != -1 ? str.substring(index + term.length()) : str;
    }
}
```